# Webpack copy and order priority

Tags: webpack

I've been searching for answer to this, but keep coming up short. I have a webpack build setup for my project, and I need to copy the final compiled js file into a second location. Problem is, I can't seem to find a way to make sure the copy command is run AFTER the final files are created.

I'm currently using the copy-webpack-plugin npm package to copy a bunch of other stuff, and this is the only thing I can't seem to do. What, if any, options do I have to copy a file AFTER the dist files are create?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone dealing with similar issues, I ended up finding and switching over to [filemanager-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gregnb/filemanager-webpack-plugin) as it allows for more control over tasks that run before and after the bundle process.